# Dynamics CRM 365 - How to refresh page without save and not show unsaved changes popup

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

We are running Microsoft Dynamics 365 Version 1612 (8.2.5.4) (DB 8.2.5.4) on-premises and trying to refresh entity page from JS without save and without "You have unsaved changes, do you want to proceed" pop up window showing.

Use case is that user changes some fields and then clics a custom button, that launches backend process from JS and when it finishes we need to refresh the page to see results of that process.
Issue is that we don't CRM save those changed values so some fields are dirty and pop up shows on refresh if user wants to proceed, which we are trying to get rid of as we know that there are some unsaved changes.

I went through every single option that I found online and none of them worked as all showed pop up window.
All of these used separately and in different combinations.

```
window.onbeforeunload=null

window.addEventListener("beforeunload",(event)=>{
    return null;
})

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

Xrm.Page.data.refresh(false);

Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName(), Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId());
```

I am running out of options to block that window, is there some other way to block it?
Other options that I though of is to hijack save function so that it actually doesn't save anything except undo dirty fields or just to undo all dirty fields in general somehow but couldn't find any post about it so it might seem impossible?

Comment: Have you tried [ResetForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-form#resetform) or [form.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) before changing the page?

Comment: @Christopher OP is referring to model driven forms, not canvas apps.

Comment: @Pushtik Can't you make the custom button responsible for undoing the changes on the fields after having launched the background process?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I think it should be no problem if I knew how to do so. I was told by my colleague that once you change the value in form and then start JS function with button, you don't have initial value available.

Comment: @Pushtik That is true, but you can have the onload handler cache those initial values.

Comment: @Pushtik made any progress?

Answer (score 2):

The `Xrm.Page` API does not provide a function that restores the original value of an attribute (field) or clears its "isDirty" property.

Instead this approach can help:

- In the form's `onLoad` handler store (cache) the values of the fields (attributes) that eventually need to be reset to their original value.
- In the handler of the custom button launch the backend process and then set the fields to their cached values.